# Magento: create a public url of a custom .phtml file

Tags: magento

I have created a custom .phtml file located at /app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/prod_attribs.phtml

on /app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml i want to create a hyperlink of prod_attribs.phtml

Please advise how to create hyperlink of this newly created prod_attribs.phtml file

EDIT:

on phtml file /app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/catalog/produc‌​t/view/addtocart.pht‌​ml i want to make a hyper link which should point to newly created file "prod_attribs.phtml" something like  " class="various">Configure Here

which when clicked should open the prod_attribs.phtml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: on phtml file /app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml i want to make a hyper link which should point to newly created file "prod_attribs.phtml" 

something like <a href="<?php print Mage::getUrl('catalog/product/view/prod_attribs.phtml'); ?> " class="various">Configure Here</a> 

which when clicked should open the prod_attribs.phtml

Comment: You need to put your existing code, your requirements, and describe what's not working for you in your existing code. Then you're likely to get help.

Comment: @Enigmativity i need help on this please. do you need more information?

Comment: @Enigmativity on addtocart.phtml i am having following code

[link]<a href="<?php print Mage::getUrl('catalog/product/view/', array('prod_attribs.phtml')); ?> " class="various">Configure Here</a>[/link]

and i want this click to open phtml page residing in /app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/prod_attribs.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution for this is.
first create cms page with below code.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/prod_attribs.phtml"}}
```

So,now you have link for that cms page which you get by clicking preview from cms grid page.

now you can use that link into your addtocart.phtml file like you said "`<a href="cms page link" class="various">Configure Here</a>`

which when clicked it should open the prod_attribs.phtml content.

Thanks

Comment: Thats a good and easy suggestion otherwise you have to go with controllers which will not be as easy if you're not experienced.